# Angularjs - Can you define types inside your controller?

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to define types inside of an Angularjs controller?  I have an array of objects that regularly reads and writes user input to a database and wanted to enforce types on the objects attributes like int and float. Is this possible?

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

$scope.Rows = [{
    OptionOne: "",
    OptionTwo: "",
    OptionThree: "",
    OptionFour: "",

    Hrs: 0,
    Mins: 0,
    Secs: 0
}];

}]);
```

Comment: Read up on angular form validation and how it integrates with `ng-model`

Comment: Also take a look at TypeScript

Comment: There's also [Flow](http://flowtype.org), by Facebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're describing TypeScript, which is a type safe language.  JavaScript is not type safe, meaning you cannot enforce types.